# Show progress before use winrt currentframe.navigate

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying to make a menu in the application for winrt with Gridviev.
The cell contains gridviev RingProgress, bound to viewmodel property isBusy.

When I call the following code, the progress is visible, but if you include the transition to a different page, the current page is at the time stands still and does not display the progress.

I will appreciate any help!

```
    private void MenuGridView_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedItem = e.ClickedItem as PageMenuItem;
        if (clickedItem != null)
        {
            clickedItem.IsProgress = true;

            //This code suspends page
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                     () => CurrentFrame.Navigate(clickedItem.NavigationInfo));
        }
    }
```